# how to get text of anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have rows in `li`, inside `li` I have anchor tag. I want to get the value of that anchor tag. I am getting the `id` of `li` but I am not getting the value of the anchor tag.

```
<div class="testcaselist_row">
    <ul>
        <li id="tc_1" class="clickTestCaseRow">
            <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff!important;">aa</a>
            <a class="delete deleteTestCase_h"></a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickTestCaseRow', function (e) {
    var clickId = this.id;
    // getting the id
    alert($(this).closest('a').val()); // getting undefined
});
```

Expected aa value

Comment: did you try first as I have in my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You need `find()` instead of `closest()` and `text()` instead of `val()`. You want to find elements descendant of source of event find will get descendants on the other hand closest looks in ancestors.

The `val()` is used for input elements like `textbox`, `checkbox` etc. You need html or text for element like `div`, `span`, `a` etc.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Xqsvq/)**

```
 alert($(this).find('a').text());
```

To get the next element you can use eq(index) or next

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Xqsvq/3/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickTestCaseRow', function (e) { 
    alert($(this).find('a:eq(1)').text());
    //alert($(this).find('a').next().text());
});
```

Comment: can you look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669120/how-to-restrict-node-or-stop-from-droping-when-parent-node-node-have-child

Comment: this code will find last a tag ... he want first a tag

Comment: @Anri, my code is giving the first a tag, although I could not find in question what anchor tag he want. I have explained the method to get the next or last tag in my answer.

Comment: @Adil he want a first one "Expected aa value" and find is not used for get a fist child of a tag

Comment: Did you check the first Live Demo link, it gives text for first anchor that is 'aa'

Answer (score 1):

In your context *this* is *li* element, you can write code as @Adil suggested or use *e.target* which is the element which caused event to trigger (in this case the anchor tag you need).

So: http://jsfiddle.net/VwqLQ/

html:

```
<div class="testcaselist_row">
    <ul>
        <li id="tc_1" class="clickTestCaseRow">
            <a href="#">aa</a>
            <a class="delete deleteTestCase_h"></a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickTestCaseRow', function (e) {
    var clickId = this.id;
    console.log($(e.target).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use to find **first()** a tag and **text()** to get the content

first() returns first a tag inside li tag

see documentation http://api.jquery.com/first/

```
alert($(this).first('a').text());// getting undefine
```

OR

```
alert($('.clickTestCaseRow a').first().text());// getting undefine
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 alert($(this).find('a').html());
```

Insted of

```
 alert($(this).closest('a').val());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zE2eM/23/)